Benders subproblem optimality cut value differs from subproblem obj function
I'm working on implementing Benders decomposition for a MILP problem. The approach is quite straightforward: all integer variables are assigned to the Master Problem (MP), while all continuous variables are included in the Sub-problem (SP).
Given the solution $(\bar{y},\bar{z})$ from the MP, my sub-problem is formulated as follows:
\begin{align}
\min \;& c^Tx + d^Tw + h^Tv \\
\text{s.t.} \\ 
& q\leqslant B\bar{y} + C\bar{z},\tag{SP.1}&[\pi^{(1)}]\\ 
& q\geqslant B\bar{y} + D\bar{z}, &[\pi^{(2)}] \tag{SP.2}\\ 
\; & q + w + v \geqslant M, &[\pi^{(3)}] \tag{SP.3}\\ 
\; & x + q = Q, & [\pi^{(4)}] \tag{SP.4}\\ 
\; & 0 \leq q \leq Q,& [rc^{(1)}] \\
\; & 0 \leq x \leq Q,& [rc^{(2)}] \\
\; & 0 \leq w \leq b,& [rc^{(3)}] \\
\; & 0 \leq v \leq e,& [rc^{(4)}] \\
\; & q,x,w,v\in R_{0}^{+}\\ 
\end{align}
where, $(q,x,w,v)$ are the continuous variables, M and Q are constants and such that each variable has a known upper-bound (Q for q and x, b for w and e for v).
Given the dual variables $\pi$ associated with each constraint in the SP such that: $\pi^{(1)} \leq 0, \pi^{(2)}, \pi^{(3)} \geq 0, \text{and}\thinspace \pi^{(4)} \text{is unrestricted}$, optimality cuts takes the form: $\eta \geqslant \pi^{(1)}(By + Cz) + \pi^{(2)}(By + Dz) + \pi^{(3)}M + \pi^{(4)}Q$.
The issue I'm encountering is that when I fix the values of the variables ($z$ and $y$) in the optimality cut, the resulting value differs from the optimal objective function value of the SP.
However, if I either remove constraint (SP.3) from the SP or modify the constraint to $q + w \geqslant M$ or $q + v \geqslant M$, I obtain same values.
Is there something I am doing wrong or overlooking? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Shouldn't the dual bound read as $\eta \ge -\pi^{(1)} (By + Cz) + \pi^{(2)} (By+Dz) + ...$? (Mind the sign before the first term)

indeed $\pi^{(1)} \leq 0 $, $\pi^{(2)} , \pi^{(3)}  \geq 0 $ and $\pi^{(4)}$ is unrestricted.

When you say "fix the values", do you mean that substituting $\bar{y}$ for $y$ and $\bar{z}$ for $z$ in the optimality cut yields a value different from the SP optimum? Is it better (smaller) or worse (larger) than the SP optimum?

Yes exactly. By substituting $\bar{y}$ for $y$ and $\bar{z}$ for $z$ the resulting value of the optimality cut is worse (way larger) than the SP optimum. In particular multiplying $\pi^{(3)}$ by the constant $M$ in constraint SP.3 results in a huge constant.

The subproblem variables $q, x, w, v$ do not have upper bounds, correct?

as a matter of fact they do. Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I will update my original post.

If any of the variables hit their upper bounds in the SP solution, you need to include the dual variables of those bounds in the calculation of the constraint. Since most (all?) solvers allow the user to enter variable bounds as bounds rather than as constraints, and thus do not produce dual values for them, it is easy to miss the need to include their dual values. You can calculate the dual value of a variable bound from the reduced cost of the variable. (I provided details some time back in a blog post.)

Thank you professor Rubin. After adding the dual variables of the variables at their upper-bounds, I've obtained the same values for both the optimality cut and SP optimum. Therefore, supposing $rc^{(1)}$,$rc^{(2)}$,$rc^{(3)}$,$rc^{(4)}$ are the reduced costs for variables q, x, w, and e respectively, the new optimality cuts takes the following form: $\eta \geqslant \pi^{(1)}(By + Cz) + \pi^{(2)}(By + Dz) + \pi^{(3)}M + \pi^{(4)}Q + (rc^{(1)} + rc^{(2)})Q + rc^{(3)} b + rc^{(4)}e$ ?

That looks correct to me.
